# How to bypass self signed certificate verify in python pika to rabbitmq?

Tags: python, ssl, rabbitmq, pika

```
parameters = pika.URLParameters('amqps://<user>:<pass>@<host>/<vhost>')
connection = pika.BlockingConnection(parameters)
channel = connection.channel()
```

How can I bypass self-signed cert verify in python pika?